# Right way to draw error bars for relative (i.e. percentage) data?

Tags: statistics

It is straightforward to calculate error bars for data where each data point is independent. However, I have data in the form of relative (i.e. percent) occurrence of something, and want to make "stacked" bars out of this, i.e. where the length of the entire bar is fixed but it's divided into different colors to indicate the fraction of occurrences of each type. I.e., like this example: https://python-graph-gallery.com/13-percent-stacked-barplot/
Clearly, the bar heights within each stack here are NOT independent as they add to 100%.

I have multiple replicate samples for which these relative occurrence frequencies were measured (not referring to the multiple stacks here--EACH stack will be the average of several equivalent samples, while separate stacks will be used for SETS of NONequivalent samples). I'd like to plot error bars at the boundaries between the sub-bars to indicate the variability of the fractions across each sample set, but I'm wondering what is the correct way to do this. If I were to just take the standard deviation of the percentage immediately below each boundary, then  that creates a bias where the error bar on the topmost boundary (orange/blue in the example I linked to) has nothing to do with the actual error in the top (blue) bar. The percent orange could be almost constant while the percent blue and percent green could have huge anti-correlated variation, yet this would be obscured by a tiny error bar at the top of the orange bars.

Do error bars not make sense for this kind of bar chart at all? Or alternatively, is the correct way to calculate a separate cumulative sum for each sample, and then take the standard deviations of these cumulative sums? In other words, to compute sum1 = green_1+orange_1, sum2 = green_2+orange_2, and sum3 = green_3+orange_3, then take the SD of (sum1, sum2, sum3) rather than ever actually using the SD of (orange_1, orange_2, orange_3)?